# Firebase android impementation realtime database problem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had a problem when I try to implement `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'` I added google-services.JSON fine but when I try to add realtime database library I found

> ERROR: Android dependency 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported

I'm In real trouble whole of My work will discard if I can't find a real solution, My code works fine In client Pc.

My Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.Djiboutymodel"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/xUtils-2.5.5.jar')
   // implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    //implementation  'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation  files('libs/jxl.jar')
    implementation  files('libs/cw-deviceapi20180918.jar')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: change `minSdkVersion` to `16` and add `google()` in repositories

Comment: api might work yes, also I am not sure about it, but ``google()`` should be the first entry in the repositories section? I think I remember I read that somewhere, long time ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 minSdkVersion 14
```

into this:

```
 minSdkVersion 23
```

---

Change :

```
  repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
```

into this:

```
  repositories {
       google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Since you are using a new version of firebase, then update the application to AndroidX

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I find a solution:

1/ Migrate project to androidx.

2/ Replace

```
repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
        }
```

into

```
jcenter()
google()  // Google's Maven repository
```